# Constructing an object to return by value elsewhere

Tags: c++, node.js, c++11, v8

In a wrapper to interface the V8 JavaScript engine with C++ code, I'd like to call a C++ function passing it an object by value. The object is automatically constructed from data inside JavaScript.

The C++ function to call takes an object of type T and a template is used to generate an adapter function A, returning T by value. The problem is that the adapter function A needs to call a JavaScript function passing it another C++ function B as a callback. The object of type T is constructed in that function B. It cannot be returned back to A through JavaScript, which doesn't know how to handle the object of type T.

The simplest way is to have a local variable of type T inside function A. A pointer to it is given to B, which assigns a new value to the local variable, which A later returns, approximately like so (Some details omitted regarding how arguments are passed to callJavaScript and callback. In reality, T's constructor and thus the B function may take any number of more complicated types as parameters):

C++ code:

```
T A() {
    T data;

    callJavaScript("someJavaScriptFunction", &B, &data);

    return data;
}

void B(T *data, int importantValue) {
    *data = T(importantValue);
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
function someJavaScriptFunction(callback, dataRef) {
    callback(dataRef, getImportantValueSomehow());
}
```

But what if the type T doesn't support assignment or even have a copy constructor? Is there a way to avoid unnecessary copying? I thought of allocating empty space inside function A as a local variable:

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data;
```

Function B could then construct the object in that space using placement new, but how can I return the resulting object from A using move semantics? How to call a possible destructor correctly?

My final idea was to use more template trickery to allocate space for parameters for type T's constructor inside function A, set them through pointers from B and finally construct the object inside A, but it will get nasty if data in some parameters goes out of scope when callJavaScript returns. Is there a solution for that?

EDIT: The point of all this is to get the contents of a JavaScript object into C++. Reading the object's properties from C++ requires looking them up by name using strings. A JIT-compiled function in V8 has more direct access to the object's fields and reads of the object's properties in someJavaScriptFunction get compiled into simple pointer reads. Then it can call the C++ callback with various parameters which are reasonably fast to convert from JavaScript value handles into C++ types.

EDIT2: The simple first idea is:

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data;
::new(&data) T(); // THIS LINE ACTUALLY PLACED IN ANOTHER FUNCTION
return(*reinterpret_cast<T *>(&data));
```

But should I call the destructor for the object T constructed in data, and when to call it, and how? This is a library and adding code to the recipient of the return value is not really an option.

Comment: In function `B` you are given a pointer to `T`. Have you considered using placement new: `new(data) T(importantValue);`

Comment: @quamrana The issue is how to call the destructor... I'm adding the problematic code at the end of the question now because code doesn't seem to get formatted nicely in a comment.

Comment: So call the destructor before the placement new.

Comment: @quamrana the object needing to be destroyed is created by the placement new. I've now asked a more specific question with a working sample program at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091223/placement-new-return-by-value-and-safely-dispose-temporary-copies

Comment: Won't your object be deleted when it goes out of scope? Your function `T A();` creates it on the stack and, via NRVO as @EdMaster points out, will just move it somewhere else on the stack. Stack objects are deleted automatically.

Comment: @quamrana Everything is fine as long as it's a local variable of type T (but what if it can't be constructed with dummy data before calling JS?). But if I allocate just space for the object in A using aligned_storage and construct a T object there using placement new, and then cast it to type T in the return statement, the first copy of the object doesn't get destroyed. I've hopefully solved it using a wrapper class, the code is in the newer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091223/placement-new-return-by-value-and-safely-dispose-temporary-copies which asks if such an idea works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a wrapper around A that handles calling placement new and A's destructor. It allows the library's user to supply any class A, as long as it has a move constructor. The full code of a working test and discussion about it are found in a newer, better formulated question [Placement new, return by value and safely dispose temporary copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091223/placement-new-return-by-value-and-safely-dispose-temporary-copies) and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood completely your question, but it seems that you don't have a need to pass output parameters in your functions.

Simply have function A return a value as you already put in the question, and have B return a value.

Because of the "named return value optimization" there is no need for assignment operator nor copy constructors.  That is, if your code satisfies the requirements for "NRVO" you would be fine:

```
T B(int importantValue) { return T{importantValue}; }
```

Does not need assignment operator nor copy constructor from T.
Then, change callJavascript to not require output parameters, but return a value, and then this will work without copy constructors or assignment operator:

```
T A() { A rv{callJavascript(&B)}; return rv; }
```

In general, make it so that your functions don't require output parameters, otherwise you require your types to have copy constructors and assignment operators, or to violate the type system.

By the way, make `callJavascript` such that it is a template that takes a callable as argument.

Comment: Problem is that B's return value goes to the V8 JavaScript engine, and is ultimately returned back to A through someJavaScriptFunction. Temporarily wrapping the value into a handle that can be stored in a JS variable is a bit wasteful.

Comment: Can you capture Javascript return values? If you can then just do it

Comment: It seems B's only purpose is to capture the integer that `getImportantValueSomehow` produces.  If you can't capture the value of any arbitrary type, then use this technique to capture the value of the integer and call B from A explicitly.  I fail to see your problem.

Comment: The issue is cases where B takes more parameters and someJavaScriptFunction has to do actual work to compute them. They may also be strings or other types that get garbage collected when the JavaScript function returns. It could instead return a complicated object for A to process, but the whole reason for this approach is process the objects in JavaScript and pass raw data to C++ using types it can process more easily.