# Placement new, return by value and safely dispose temporary copies

Tags: c++, c++11, placement-new

Due to complicated circumstances (explained in earlier question [Constructing an object to return by value elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077823/constructing-an-object-to-return-by-value-elsewhere)) I want to return an object by value from function X, but create it in another function Y indirectly called by X. Between them there is 3rd party code in the call stack that won't co-operate in passing the object around. X can only pass pointers to Y and receive a pointer back.

I've come up with a solution using placement new but mainly worry whether it's portable, doesn't invoke any undefined behavior and safely disposes of allocated objects. Any improvement to avoid unnecessary copies is also welcome. Here's an entire test program which was written to be as minimal as possible:

```
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        printf("Create A @ %p\n", this);
    }

    A(const A &other) {
        printf("Copy A @ %p\n", this);
        printf("From another A %s @ %p\n", other.valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", &other);
        valid = other.valid;
    }

    A(A &&other) {
        printf("Move A @ %p\n", this);
        printf("From another A %s @ %p\n", other.valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", &other);
        valid = other.valid;
    }

    ~A() {
        printf("Destroy A %s @ %p\n", valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", this);
        valid = false;
    }

    void bar() {printf("Hello, World! (A %s @ %p)\n", valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", this);}

    bool valid = true;
};

class WrapA {
public:
    WrapA() {printf("Create wrapper! (A @ %p)\n", &data);}

    ~WrapA() {
        printf("Destroy wrapper! (A %s @ %p)\n", reinterpret_cast<A *>(&data)->valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", &data);
        // Manually call destructor for instance created using placement new
        reinterpret_cast<A *>(&data)->~A();
    }

    void init() {
        ::new(&data) A();
    }

    A getA() {
        printf("Wrapper returning A %s @ %p\n", reinterpret_cast<A *>(&data)->valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", &data);

        return(*reinterpret_cast<A *>(&data));
    }

    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>::type data;
};

A debug(A data) {
    printf("Wrapper returned A %s @ %p\n", data.valid ? "OK" : "NOT OK", &data);
    return(data);
}

A test() {
    WrapA wrapper;

    wrapper.init();

    return(debug(wrapper.getA()));
}

int main(void) {
    test().bar();

    return(0);
}
```

It prints:

```
Create wrapper! (A @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde)
Create A @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde
Wrapper returning A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde
Copy A @ 0x7fff1d6a5bdf
From another A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde
Wrapper returned A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bdf
Move A @ 0x7fff1d6a5c0f
From another A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bdf
Destroy A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bdf
Destroy wrapper! (A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde)
Destroy A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5bde
Hello, World! (A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5c0f)
Destroy A OK @ 0x7fff1d6a5c0f
```

The output shows that A gets passed through 3 different memory addresses, stays valid the entire time and all copies seem to get destroyed correctly. In the example, `test` calls `init` directly, but in the real-life case, `test` calls something else with the pointer to the `wrapper` variable, and eventually `wrapper.init` gets called elsewhere receiving a number of parameters with a complicated lifetime.

Is the object created in `WrapA::init` passed safely to `main` and appropriately disposed of in `WrapA::~WrapA`? Is everything OK when `A::bar()` gets called? Are there any problems with the code?

Comment: It seems the aligned_storage can be replaced with an anonymous union, also eliminating the need for casting pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at a class that manages resources like wrapA and you need to basically ask two questions:

1. Does it correctly manage its resources: correct construction, assignment, destruction.
2. Do any of its public data or functions potentially allow for easy corruption of the resource management scheme?

Let's start with 1. I see a few potential issues:

- The class has a data member that represents the space to hold an A, but not necessarily an actual A. This is fine
- However, the constructor for wrapA doesn't construct A, but the destructor does try to destruct A. So if you ever forget to call init on a wrapA, you will get undefined behavior. I'd change this design; the most basic way would be to have a boolean flag keeping track of whether an A had actually been constructed or not.
- However, wrapA will get automatically constructed copy constructor/assignment (this is deprecated). These automatically generated functions will not correctly call A's copy constructor/assignment, since wrapA doesn't actually own an A, they will just copy A bitwise. So if A is non-trivial, these functions will not work properly. You should explicitly either write these two functions, or = delete them so you wrapA becomes uncopyable. Although, wrapA will then be both uncopyable and unmovable, so perhaps annoying to work with

As for 2:

- the getA function is fine, as it returns a copy, so does not provide a handle to internal resources

In short, wrapA is not entirely wrong, as you can use it perfectly fine (as you demonstrated). However, it's not entirely right either. It doesn't meet the guarantees you'd expect a c++ class to meet, and therefore I think it will be easy to write buggy code using wrapA. I think it will be much safer to use if you fix the issues regarding the destructor, and the copy constructor/assignment.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. WrapA is only ever used in test() and both are heavily templated so any use elsewhere is unlikely. However I realized perhaps an exception might be thrown before init gets called, so the flag is still needed. I'll also delete WrapA's auto-generated assignment functionality.

Comment: It might even be better to have WrapA's constructor default construct A() (if you are certain that A will always have a default constructor). Then you don't need as many special cases later. Your init function can then follow the CAS (copy and swap idiom), to be sure you are exception safe.

Comment: If a default constructor is always available, I could allocate A directly in test() and elsewhere assign directly to it, making WrapA unnecessary. However this is for a library that should work with any class A the user will throw at it. Unfortunately it seems I can't make this work without requiring A to anyway have a copy constructor.

Comment: You can implement it so that it works if A just has a move constructor, in this case the getA method will "steal" the A from WrapA, and leave a different, but valid A behind. This might be a good idea anyhow for efficiency if A is a type that has non-stack resources (like heap memory). However, unless you know for sure that you'll need to deal with types that aren't default constructible, I'd probably take the easy way out. Given your restrictions, it will be easier and more efficient to work with default constructible types.

Comment: Do you mean changing getA to return(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<A *>(&data))); ? It seems to work, I had no idea that could be valid! Are you sure the simpler, default constructible case would be more efficient? It would still require a move assignment, and after your latest suggestion this code (with debug() omitted) requires a single move constructor call. It seems this more complicated approach is, at worst, equally efficient.

Comment: Yes. If A is a type that purely lives on the stack, this buys you nothing, but if e.g. A is a std::vector, this will be much more efficient. If you do this, I'd probably use a boolean and set and check it appropriately. For example, if you call getA twice in a row, the second A is only guaranteed to be an A that is in a valid state, and nothing else. You probably don't want to do that by accident. Also, if you feel that I've answered your question, please accept my answer :-)